# What exactly should I test for a controller action method that returns a View with ViewModel

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core-2.0, xunit

I have written down my very first unit test for a controller action method that use  Moq framework to mock the repository. In this test, I can count the number of returned models from the mocked repository but don't know what test should I perform to validate the viewmodel or the action result output?

```
public class HomeControllerUnitTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void IndexTest()
    {
        //Arrange
        var restaurantServiceMock = new Mock<IRestaurantDataCL>();
        var mockList = new List<Restaurant>()
        {
            new Restaurant
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "Sabatino's",
                Cuisine = CuisineType.French
            },
            new Restaurant
            {
                Id = 2,
                Name = "Sabatino's",
                Cuisine = CuisineType.Italian
            },
            new Restaurant
            {
                Id = 3,
                Name = "Sabatino's",
                Cuisine = CuisineType.German
            },
            new Restaurant
            {
                Id = 4,
                Name = "Sabatino's",
                Cuisine = CuisineType.None
            },
            new Restaurant
            {
                Id = 5,
                Name = "Sabatino's",
                Cuisine = CuisineType.None
            }
        };

        restaurantServiceMock
            .Setup(x => x.GetAll())
            .Returns(mockList);

        var greeterServiceMock = new Mock<IGreeter>();
        var greeterMessage = "Hello From Unit Test !!!!";
        greeterServiceMock
            .Setup(x => x.GetMessageOfTheDay())
            .Returns(greeterMessage);


        var controller = new HomeController(restaurantServiceMock.Object, greeterServiceMock.Object);

        //act
        var result = controller.Index();

        //Assert
        Assert.NotNull(result);
        var okResult = result.Should().BeOfType<ViewResult>().Subject;
        var restaurants = ((HomeIndexViewModel)okResult.Model).Restaurants.Should().BeAssignableTo<IEnumerable<Restaurant>>().Subject;
        restaurants.Count().Should().Be(5);

        var indexViewModel = okResult.Model.Should().BeAssignableTo<HomeIndexViewModel>().Subject;

        Assert.IsAssignableFrom<HomeIndexViewModel>(indexViewModel);

    }
}
```

Comment: Don't unit test controllers. Valuable unit tests are the one which test business logic. You now have to maintain a messy and fragile test which took you a lot of time to write and will bite you soon or later. What are you gains ? Which possible regressions will you catch ?

Comment: @Spotted I can see and agree with you that testing controllers can become quite messy. I wonder though why there are so many tutorials that only talk about testing the controller action methods? Is it worth writing down the basis test for the controllers. May be e.g. returned view name, redirect to action etc.?

Comment: There are such tutorials because not everyone consider testing controllers, using mocks, etc. in unit testing a bad practice. It can makes sense in some cases to unit test controllers when you have basic logic in it (if object found return it with status 200, else returns 404). Otherwise I think it's not worth it.

Comment: By the way, you can read this serie of articles on [unit testing](https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2016/06/01/unit-tests-value-proposition/) whose ideas I share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what your controller action is supposed to do, but you should for example verify that the right view was returned, whether the right view model was returned and assert the expected state of the view model. Please refer to the docs for more information about how to unit test controllers:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/unit-testing/creating-unit-tests-for-asp-net-mvc-applications-cs

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/testing?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Keep in mind that the controller logic should be minimal though. Your business logic should be implemented in the model(s).